# Redhat - Unable to generate 32-bit libopencv_java249.so ( shared object ) file

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, 32bit-64bit, redhat

Hi I'm trying to make use of one of the OpenCV functionality for image processing(Increasing the sharpness of the image). I'm using below configuration.

- RHEL6 64-bit
- Java 32- bit type
- Eclipse Luna

For the above configuration, I'm trying to generate libopencv_java249.so file using opencv installation.

For RHEL-64 & Java 64-bit type,I'm able to generate the required .so file.

But for 64-32 bit combination, the .so file is not building in lib folder.

I have followed below steps while generating files

- cd opencv-2.4.9
- mkdir release
- cd release
- cmake -D
  CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
- make
- make install

So, my question is,  can we generate 32-bit libopencv_java249.so file using RHEL64-bit 
& 32-bit java..

If not , what is the possible solution to make opencv work for RHEL64-bit 
& 32-bit java combination.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to install `ant` before running cmake. also, if the opencv code is from github, make sure to run `git checkout 2.4` (else it will build 3.0)

Comment: I have already a successful installation with 64-bit RHEL and 64-bit java... Ant is already installed on my system.. Im facing issue with only 32-bit java for generating files.